# Button Animation Issue

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, storyboard, imagebutton

I asked a previous question about adding a `TabItem` and I was told that using `Buttons` would be better and just animation to them. So I went ahead today and researched about this but I have come to an issue.

This is the `XAML` I have:

```
<Button Height="43" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsEnabled="True" IsHitTestVisible="True" Margin="363,309,0,519" Name="home_btn" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="346" >
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Image Name="Normal" Source="Images/Normal1.png" />
                        <Image Name="Hover" Source="Images/Hover1.png" Opacity="0"/>
                        <Image Name="Pressed" Source="Images/view3.png" Opacity="0" Width="346" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="MouseDownTimeLine">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Pressed" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Pressed" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="274" To="300" Duration="00:00:00">
                            </DoubleAnimation>

                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="MouseUpTimeLine">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Pressed" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.25" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="MouseEnterTimeLine">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Hover" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.00" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="MouseExitTimeLine">

                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Normal" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.00" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                        </Storyboard>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="ButtonBase.IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseDownTimeLine}"/>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseUpTimeLine}"/>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseEnterTimeLine}"/>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseExitTimeLine}"/>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
```

From this when I hover over my First image it will trigger the second image. The difference between these two is just the color, so it's not the problem.

When I click the button I want an arrow to appear next to the box (*so i need the canvas to grow bigger*) I created my Images in Photoshop and the third image I made bigger but it doesn't work, this is what happens.

[image][image]

As you can see from the second picture I want to aligned from the left and come out at the right. I have tried `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` and this doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure what "aligned from the left and come out at the right" means visually, give an example of what you'd like and we can fix you up. In the meantime though, I'd ditch the images and just use xaml Path's to keep it cleaner and avoid the extra files.

Comment: Why is using a canvas important.  Would a StackPanel Orientation=Horizontal be useful?